# SQL Complex Query w/ Inner Join

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have 2 tables, 1 called Employee and 1 called Salary. Employee table consists of Emp_Name, Emp_Address, Emp_ID & Salary table consists of Salary_Details and Emp_ID. > Can you write down a query for retrieving the Salary_Details of 1 of the employee based on last name using Inner Join?

Comment: That looks like a homework question. So rather than ask others to do the work for you, show what you have tried and what you have trouble with. P.S. there is nothing complex about the question.

Comment: It's not a homework question. And for someone that is a beginner to SQL it is complex. If you don't have anything nice or supportive to contribute you shouldn't comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but this might help you:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Salary s ON e.Emp_ID = s.Emp_ID
WHERE e.Emp_Name = 'EMPLOYEENAME'
```

That will give you back all fields from Employee and Salary for an Employee with the name = 'EMPLOYEENAME' (which you can exchange then).

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the columns returned as needed depending on your app...

```
SELECT e.Emp_Name, e.Emp_ID, s.Salary_Details
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Salary s USING (Emp_ID)
WHERE e.Emp_Name = 'Smith';
```

The `USING` keyword is kind of obscure and works only if the join column is named identically in both tables. The previous answer with `ON` instead of `USING` will work in all cases. I like `USING` as a personal preference.